# GCE 8 GPU instance randomnly reboots while training is running

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have an 8 GPU GCE instance that randomnly reboots in the middle of a training routine. This happened a couple of times. The instance also appears to stay down for quite a while before it comes back up. I found some traces in the kernel log of a dump that looks like it might be the cause (?). Any ideas what I can do about this?

The configuration is pretty ordinary : An ubuntu instance running a python 3 Tensorflow App that's training on images and the Nvidia drivers are installed with the cuda toolkit.

The log is shown below. The last few lines indicating the system is booting up but nearly after 10 hours it appears

```
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749736] Call Trace:
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749737]  <IRQ>  [<ffffffff813f8dd3>] dump_stack+0x63/0x90
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749746]  [<ffffffff810ddd33>] __report_bad_irq+0x33/0xc0
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749747]  [<ffffffff810de0c7>] note_interrupt+0x247/0x290
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749749]  [<ffffffff810db277>] handle_irq_event_percpu+0x167/0x1d0
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749750]  [<ffffffff810db31e>] handle_irq_event+0x3e/0x60
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749752]  [<ffffffff810de639>] handle_fasteoi_irq+0x99/0x150
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749756]  [<ffffffff8103119d>] handle_irq+0x1d/0x30
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749758]  [<ffffffff8184341b>] do_IRQ+0x4b/0xd0
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749761]  [<ffffffff81841502>] common_interrupt+0x82/0x82
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749764]  [<ffffffff81085d5e>] ? __do_softirq+0x7e/0x290
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749766]  [<ffffffff810860e3>] irq_exit+0xa3/0xb0
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749767]  [<ffffffff818434e2>] smp_apic_timer_interrupt+0x42/0x50
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749769]  [<ffffffff818417a2>] apic_timer_interrupt+0x82/0x90
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749770]  <EOI>  [<ffffffff81064606>] ? native_safe_halt+0x6/0x10
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749775]  [<ffffffff81038e1e>] default_idle+0x1e/0xe0
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749776]  [<ffffffff8103962f>] arch_cpu_idle+0xf/0x20
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749780]  [<ffffffff810c454a>] default_idle_call+0x2a/0x40
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749781]  [<ffffffff810c48b1>] cpu_startup_entry+0x2f1/0x350
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749798]  [<ffffffff810517c4>] start_secondary+0x154/0x190
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.749799] handlers:
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.752277] [<ffffffffc2b034e0>] nvidia_isr [nvidia] threaded [<ffffffffc2b03eb0>] nvidia_isr_kthread_bh [nvidia]
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.762984] [<ffffffffc2b034e0>] nvidia_isr [nvidia] threaded [<ffffffffc2b03eb0>] nvidia_isr_kthread_bh [nvidia]
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.773705] [<ffffffffc2b034e0>] nvidia_isr [nvidia] threaded [<ffffffffc2b03eb0>] nvidia_isr_kthread_bh [nvidia]
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.784444] [<ffffffffc2b034e0>] nvidia_isr [nvidia] threaded [<ffffffffc2b03eb0>] nvidia_isr_kthread_bh [nvidia]
Jun  7 19:23:59 gpu-8-2 kernel: [62064.795096] Disabling IRQ #10
Jun  8 05:27:43 gpu-8-2 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
Jun  8 05:27:43 gpu-8-2 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpu
Jun  8 05:27:43 gpu-8-2 kernel: [    0.000000] Initializing cgroup subsys cpuacct
Jun  8 05:27:43 gpu-8-2 kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 4.4.0-79-generic (buildd@lcy01-30) (gcc version 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) ) #100-Ubuntu SMP Wed May 
17 19:58:14 UTC 2017 (Ubuntu 4.4.0-79.100-generic 4.4.67)
```

Comment: This seems like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44481549/google-compute-engine-vm-constantly-crashes?noredirect=1#comment75975339_44481549 where the machine is crashing cause of the usage. Could you share the usage graph to confirm this?

Comment: On the contrary the instance is underutilized. Here is the usage graph for the last 7 days : [Usage Graph](http://imgur.com/a/yfRCv)

Comment: That's strange. The constant CPU usage. Could you share the disk bytes graph?

Comment: [Disk Bytes for the last 7 days](http://imgur.com/a/Haq9o)

Comment: @VikramTiwari any ideas what might be causing this? Any debugging tips?

Comment: I think it might be something specific to Tensorflow and maybe the drivers for Nvidia. I don't have experience debugging them. You should ask your question on cloud community slack channel. [Join slack channel](https://gcp-slack.appspot.com/)