# Google Compute Engine VM constantly crashes

Tags: crash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-endpoints

On the Compute Engine VM in us-west-1b, I run 16 vCPUs near 99% usage. After a few hours, the VM automatically crashes. This is not a one-time incident, and I have to manually restart the VM.

There are a few instances of CPU usage suddenly dropping to around 30%, then bouncing back to 99%.

There are no logs for the VM at the time of the crash. Is there any other way to get the error logs?

How do I prevent VMs from crashing?

[CPU usage graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBHby.png)

Comment: What do you mean by a VM crash? Are your processes being stopped or the VM itself stops?

Comment: All processes stop, but the VM doesn't stop. Connecting by SSH pulls up the SSH window, but doesn't actually connect.

Comment: Okay. This could be your CPU saying that your process is out of space. You might wanna look into Kernel tuning where you can increase the limits on the number of active processes on your VM/OS. Or you can try using a bigger machine. In short, your machine is falling short on resources and hence in order to keep the OS up, it shuts down the processes. SSH is one of those processes. Once you reset the machine, all comes back to normal.

Comment: Ok thanks, why doesn't it crash in the first few hours though? The number of active processes don't change, and the beam search I'm running clears its memory every 15 minutes (because it is iterative).

Could it be something about Python's process / memory allocation?

Comment: How CPU decides to quit a process varies in many ways. It could simply be that a process has consistently stayed up for way long time to consume too many resources. Any OS that you run on GCP is also custom hardened by Google to make sure that they can limit malicious capabilities of processes running on such machines.
Yes, it could be that python's process is not clearing up memory properly and leaving some memory which ends up causing overflow and hence crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be your process manager saying that your processes are out of resources. You might wanna look into Kernel tuning where you can increase the limits on the number of active processes on your VM/OS and their resources. Or you can try using a bigger machine with more physical resources. In short, your machine is falling short on resources and hence in order to keep the OS up, process manager shuts down the processes. SSH is one of those processes. Once you reset the machine, all comes back to normal.

How process manager/kernel decides to quit a process varies in many ways. It could simply be that a process has consistently stayed up for way long time to consume too many resources. Also, one thing to note is that OS images that you use to create a VM on GCP is custom hardened by Google to make sure that they can limit malicious capabilities of processes running on such machines.

One of the best ways to tackle this is:

- increase the resources of your VM
- then go back to code and find out if there's something that is leaking in the process or memory
- if all fails, then you might wanna do some kernel tuning to make sure your processes have higer priority than other system process. Though this is a bad idea since you could end up creating a zombie VM.